# Linux: find file names with 4 or 5 characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-findutils

How can I find file names consisting of either 4 or 5 characters?

For file names with 4 characters, I can use `find . -name ????.tgz`, but how to I expand this to length either 4 or 5?

Comment: If you can use find to get all files with 4 character long names, and use it to get all files with 5 character long names... well... it does have an or operator that would let you get both.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing than using two finds with an operator in between?

Comment: It only takes one find invocation...

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: @jww You didn't read the question carefully. OP did write a `find` command (it's just not formatted correctly).

Comment: do not forget to accept answer that helped you the most

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution:

```
find . \( -name "????.cpp" -o -name "?????.cpp" \)
```

`-o` is for logical OR

just replace `.cpp` with `.tgz` or whatever you want. There is also this regex version that would do the same thing:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^./[a-zA-Z]{4,5}\.cpp$'
```

in regex `^` is start symbol `^./` means starts with `./`. `[a-zA-Z]{4,5}` means followed by 4 to 5 characters, `\.` means **.** where `\` is escape character `\.cpp$` means ends with `.cpp`

If file name contains numbers instead of `[a-zA-Z]` do `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. So it will look like this:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^./[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,5}\.cpp$'
```

Comment: This will match files like `foo.f.bar`

Comment: @oliv it does not batch foo.f.bar, but there is a mistake :(. It matches `./dddd/cpp` :(

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
printf '%s\n' **/?????(?).tgz
```

- `extglob`: enables [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)
- `globstar`: [`**`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories
- `?`: matches any single character
- `?(pattern-list)`: matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns

---

Or simply:

```
printf '%s\n' **/????.tgz **/?????.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `find` command:

```
find -type f -regextype egrep -regex ".*/[^./]{4,5}\.[^./]+$"
```

The regular expression is set catch any basename file with 4 or 5 characters.
Note this regex applies on the full name, including path.